# Ajax success actions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When someone clicks on the "like" button, I am checking in database if the photo was already liked by this person. I am using ajax to check this.

When photo was already liked, the success msg says "already liked", otherwise its empty string.

The problem is that increasing the "current likes" isnt working. I tried to use alert to see the number and it always shows the first number from the first line, its not getting increased by `currentLikes++`.

What happens actually? I defined the variable globally.

```
var currentLikes = $(this).next('span').text(); 

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/save_like",
    success: function(msg){
        addLike(msg);
    }
}); 

function addLike(msg){
    if(msg !== 'already liked'){
        currentLikes++;
    }
alert(currentLikes); 
$(this).next('span').html(currentLikes);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines: `alert(currentLikes);` and `$(this).next('span').html(currentLikes);` are not inside your AJAX code and will execute BEFORE the AJAX call has completed. Move that code into the `addLike` function to see the correct value.

Also, change the `currentLikes = currentLikes++` code to `currentLikes++` because the `++` is at the end of your expression and so it is a "post-increment" operator, it means that the value won't increase until AFTER the current statement is done evaluating. Had you written: `currentLikes = ++currentLikes` and used a "pre-increment" operator, the value would be increased before the rest of the expression was evaluated and it would work, but just saying `currentLikes++` (without reassigning back to `currenLikes` is better - - it ups the value and stores it in the current variable.

Also, `this` won't refer to the element you want it to in the callback because `this` is volatile in JavaScript - - it's object binding changes depending on how the code that contains it is invoked, so you'll need to update that will a correct reference. If you save a reference to the element you wish to work with (and not a property of that element), you can refer to that element later with the variable.

Also, you are getting the original like count out of a `span` and that will come back to you as a string, you should convert that to a number before doing math with it.

Finally, verify that `msg` is in fact NOT returning `'already liked' EXACTLY AS YOU HAVE IT IN QUOTES. Remember, strings are literals and they are case-sensitive. If there's even an extra space in`msg`, your code will not work properly.

```
// Store a reference to the likes element (not any property value of it)
var currentLikeElement = $(this).next('span'); 

// Now, get the old like count out of the DOM and convert to a number
var likeCount = parseInt(currentLikeElement.text(), 10);

alert(likeCount);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/save_like",
    success: function(msg){
        // Let's make sure msg is cleaned up and ready for comparison
        // by trimming any leading or trailing spaces off of it and forcing
        // it to all lower-case (because we'll be comparing it to lower-
        // case later).
        msg = msg.trim().toLowerCase();
        addLike(msg);
    }
}); 

function addLike(msg){
  console.log(msg);  // <--  What does this return?
  if(msg !== 'already liked'){
        likeCount++;
  }
  alert(likeCount); 

  // Inject the new like count into the stored object reference:
  currentLikeElement.text(likeCount);
}
```

Comment: `$(this).next('span').html(currentLikes);` should also be in the `addLike` function - though `this` wont be right

Comment: Hmm it is really strange... even when i put this `alert` right after the `currentLikes = currentLikes++` it shows me 0. So it doesnt get increased at all

Comment: Hmm it looks really good but console says `currentLikes.html is not a function`

Comment: Yes I do. Not sure what is wrong here. Im not good in js. I am sure we are on a good way to finish this anyway :D

Comment: @divHelper11 I just made an update to the answer to account for a new variable I added that should make things easier to understand. Take another look.

Comment: Damn its 4 at night. I already see your point and giving you the best answer but ill fix this issue when i get some sleep haha.
Looks like the problem now is that we are using an object as a number and trying to increase it. Anyways you helped me a lot. Thank you!

Comment: @divHelper11 Code always looks better in the morning! ;)

Answer (score 2):

replace `currentLikes = currentLikes++;` with `currentLikes++;`

and put `$(this).next('span').html(currentLikes);` into your addLike function

Comment: actually don't use $(this) here and there. Better assign to variable when the context is correct and use that variable everywhere.

Comment: Can i save "this" into variable :D?

Comment: I mean, I am sure this is the problem right now but im nto sure how to access my `this` from another place. Damn

Comment: @divHelper11 See my answer for explanation on how to store the element.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the your sample code, try to put your like count update script within **addLike(msg)** function.

```
function addLike(msg){
  if(msg !== 'already liked'){
    currentLikes++;
    $(this).next('span').html(currentLikes);
  }
}
```